# Uploaded an app on app store no icon on organizer

Tags: iphone, xcode

I uploaded an app that shows no icon on organizer, but shows icon on iphone simulator and the real iPhone. Will there be any problem? Do I need to make sure the app icon shows up after I archive it?

Answer (score 0):

If the icons show up on the simulator and your test device, there should be no problem. Just to be sure, you can try to completely delete the app from your device, clean the project and rebuild. If the icon shows up, then the Organizer is messing up something.